# How to get user defined SQLException number with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

My stored procedure is throwing custom errors to handle validation within a multi user web app. This is working as expected in SQL Server with error number 50001 being returned however when my C# code catches the error it always has the error number 50000 instead of 50001 therefore I cannot treat the errors differently.

How can I catch error number 50001? Note that I am using Dapper to execute all stored procedures.

**SQL**

```
THROW 50001, 'Client already has an Active Visit! THIS IS DEV!!!!',1;

Msg 50001, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Client already has an Active Visit! THIS IS DEV!!!!
```

**C#**

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    var errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
    var msg = errorHandler.ErrorMessage(ex);
    if (ex.Number == 50001)
    {
        return BadRequest(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(500, msg);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
    return StatusCode(500, errorHandler.ErrorMessage(ex));
}
```

**EXAMPLE**
[image: example]

Comment: Are you using ErrorHandler from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.errorhandler?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server error 50000 is reserved for general user defined message, so it sounds like it's not finding error 50001 in `sys.messages`. You can try to add the error using the stored procedure `sp_addmessage`.

Once that is done, you can call it like this:

```
RAISERROR(50001, 1, 1)
```

Another reason it could be error 50000 is if you are raising the SQL error in a SQL TRY/CATCH as that will always return a 50000 error code.

---

Just tried this code myself:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("THROW 50001,'error',1;", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And that does return ex.Number 50001 so it must be a problem in your SQL. Like I said above, it could be caused by a TRY/CATCH as this won't save the original error code number.

Comment: thanks you were right. the throw statement was inside the TRY/CATCH so once i moved it outside this block the custom error code 50001 came through to my c# exception